# how to stop re-rendering of child component if parent update the context or state in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-context

how to stop re-rendering of child component  if parent update the  context or state in react js ?

I am already using `React.memo` still it is re-rendering.

this is my child component

```
const Ab = () => {
  console.log("---ff-ddd");
  const pageContext = useContext(PageContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      pageContext.updateGlobalMenu({});
    }, 5000);
  }, []);
  return <div>ddd</div>;
};

export default React.memo(Ab);
```

I am updating the context. I want it update the context value but not re-render the child component

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  const [globalMenu, setGlobalMenu] = useState("");

  const updateGlobalMenu = (menuContent) => {
    setGlobalMenu(menuContent);
  };

  return (
    <PageContext.Provider
      value={{
        updateGlobalMenu
      }}
    >
      <Ab />
    </PageContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-bartik-3cnqvf?file=/pages/index.js:156-470

if you see it print **two times console**. it means it is re-rendering two times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PageContext`'s value changes, then any component consuming that context (including `Ab`) will render. React.memo cannot stop this. In your case you're changing the value on every render, so you have room to improve it by memoizing the context value. That way, the value won't change unless it needs to:

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  const [globalMenu, setGlobalMenu] = useState("");

  const updateGlobalMenu = useCallback((menuContent) => {
    setGlobalMenu(menuContent);
  }, []);

  const value = useMemo(() => ({
    updateGlobalMenu
  }), [updateGlobalMenu]);

  return (
    <PageContext.Provider value={value}>
      <Ab />
    </PageContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I found using useCallback to wrap my context's state updater methods resolved this question's issue for me.

My state updating methods were being re-evaluated on every re-render when any of the context's state was modified. By wrapping it in the useCallback, the main state is free to update and trigger re-renders in children using the main context state, but child components that only use the update methods don't re-render now! Great!

@Nicholas' answer above guided me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also, in addition to memoisation from the previous answer, split your "api" and "data" portion of the state into two different providers.

`updateGlobalMenu` will be in `PageContextAPI` provider, `globalMenu` will be in `PageContextData` provider. That way when you update the data, only the provider with the data will be re-rendered.

Take a look at this article, I covered this technique in detail here:https://www.developerway.com/posts/how-to-write-performant-react-apps-with-context